# Creating nested list with different shapes with numpy

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

I want to create a list of lists of random numbers, h[i,j,k], with axes of different lenghts.

For that I have tried

```
import numpy as np
import random as rng

NBR1 = 2
NBR2 = [2,3,1]
    
list = np.array([np.array([np.array([rng.uniform(-1,1) for k in range(NBR2[i+1])]) for j in range(NBR2[i])]) for i in range(NBR1)])
```

Without the np.array, I can observe in the Variable Explorer that the list of lists is indeed of the shape I need. With the np.array, not only I cannot dig deep within the list layers (in the Variable Explorer) but I also get the warning:

*VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.*

In any case, when I try to extract a vector from this list of lists it comes out with the wrong shape. For instance

```
testtt = list[0][:][0]
```

Should have lenght 2, but it has 3 (I may be just getting this indexing wrong -- but the vector h[0,;;,0] should have length 2).

What am I doing wrong? I'm an absolute begginer and appreciate any insigths.

**Edit:** it appears numpy is not ideal for dealing with non-homogeneous lists, I believe that is the core of my problem.

**Edit2:** The list of lists I want to obtain is of the following form:

[image]

And writing `testtt = list[0][:][0]` I was hoping to get {h[0,0,0], h[0,1,0]}.

Comment: Please specify what is rng.uniform?

Comment: @Roxy sorry! It is the uniform() function of the random module. I have added that to the code

Comment: I don't seem to get a warning.

Comment: @Roxy strange. Could it be I'm not updated?

Comment: I posted an answer, but reading again your question, it is almost certainly not what you want: I noticed the `lst` (please don't overwrite the `list` keyword) you are creating is _not_ the shape that you want. What is the (jagged) shape of the result you need? As you note, `numpy` arrays cannot be jagged, but a list of arrays can. The key is to understand what you mean with `NBR1` and `NBR2` in terms of desired shape.

Comment: @PierreD thank you for your help! I have updated the question with the information you required. It should be much easier to understand, now.

Answer (score 0):

Is the following what you are looking for (a list of np.arrays)?

```py
np.random.seed(0)  # for reproducible example --remove when using
lst = [np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size) for size in zip(NBR2, NBR2[1:])]

>>> lst
[array([[ 0.09762701,  0.43037873,  0.20552675],
        [ 0.08976637, -0.1526904 ,  0.29178823]]),
 array([[-0.12482558],
        [ 0.783546  ],
        [ 0.92732552]])]
```